# How can I define symbols but not have them show up in the front end?

Tags: front-end, symbols, undocumented, user-interface

I have a huge set of packages with, arguably, far too many functions. Paring down the number of functions, while a good thing to do eventually, is something I just don't want to spend the time on right now. Rather I just want a way to turn off the symbols from showing up in the front-end by default.

I know this is possible as `DeclareKnownSymbols` doesn't show up or autocorrect until I have prepend `` System` ``  to the name. And things like `` DataPaclets`GetDataPacletResource `` don't show up black despite the fact that they have values.

How can I set this up myself?

Comment: Related: [115649](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115649/prevent-autocompletion-for-symbols-in-contexts-other-than-private)

Answer (score 13):

#### Core Function

Here's a single function that does all this coloring stuff:

```
FESetSymbolColoring[
   {syms__},
   cont : _String | Automatic : Automatic,
   contPath : {__String} | Automatic : Automatic,
   which :
    "Undefined" | "Removed" | "Defined" | "Cleared" |
     1 | 2 | 3 | 
     4 | {(1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | "Undefined" | "Removed" | "Defined" | 
         "Cleared") ..}
   ] :=
  With[{
    stuff =
     Map[
       Function[Null,
        If[StringQ@Unevaluated[#],
         Replace[
          StringSplit[#, "`", 2],
          {{c_, s_} :> {c <> "`", s}, {s_} :> {$Context, s}}
          ],
         {Context@#, SymbolName@Unevaluated@#}
         ],
        HoldAllComplete
        ],
       HoldComplete[syms]
       ] // Apply[List],
    whi =
     Replace[Flatten@{which},
      {
       "Undefined" -> 1,
       "Removed" -> 2,
       "Defined" -> 3,
       "Cleared" -> 4
       },
      1
      ]
    },
   FrontEndExecute@
    FrontEnd`UpdateKernelSymbolContexts[
     Replace[cont, Automatic :> $Context],
     Replace[contPath, Automatic :> $ContextPath],
     KeyValueMap[
      With[{symlist = #2},
        Prepend[Replace[cont, Automatic :> #]]@
         Fold[
          ReplacePart[#, #2 -> symlist] &,
          ConstantArray[{}, 4],
          whi
          ]
        ] &,
      GroupBy[stuff, First -> Last]
      ]
     ]
   ];
FESetSymbolColoring[s_, a___] :=
  FESetSymbolColoring[{s}, a];
FESetSymbolColoring~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
```

Use it like:

```
FESetSymbolColoring[{a,b,c},"Defined"]
```

or

```
FESetSymbolColoring[{a,b,c},"Removed"]
```

---

The place to start, here, is actually `FrontEndResourceString["GetFEKernelInit"]` (which just pulls from a `GetFEKernelInit.tr` file).

And in it we'll find the definition of `` System`DeclareKnownSymbols `` but also this curious function: `` Internal`SymbolList ``.

And we'll see that it's often used as `` Internal`SymbolList[True] ``. The trick, though, is to set use `` Internal`SymbolList[False] `` which just turns off the last part of the output to `` Internal`SymbolList[] ``, which is used by `` FrontEnd`Private`GetCurrentSymbolsContexts `` (I assume) to set the coloring. So that's really the trick. Just make a block like:

```
FEHiddenBlock[expr_] :=
  (
   Internal`SymbolList[False];
   (Internal`SymbolList[True]; #) &@expr
   );
FEHiddenBlock~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
```

and any symbols you define within it won't be recognized by the FE until you call `` System`DeclareKnownSymbols `` on their symbol names (if they're in `$Context`) or call this on the symbols:

```
FEUnhideSymbols[syms__] :=
  With[{stuff =
     Map[
       Function[Null, {Context@#, SymbolName@Unevaluated@#}, 
        HoldAllComplete],
       HoldComplete[syms]
       ] // Apply[List]
    },
   KeyValueMap[
     FrontEndExecute@
       FrontEnd`UpdateKernelSymbolContexts[
        #,
        $ContextPath,
        {{#, {}, {}, #2, {}}}
        ] &,
     GroupBy[stuff, First -> Last]
     ];
   ];
FEUnhideSymbols~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
```

Note that that will cause the FE to recognize value-less symbols.

We can also hide symbols that are recognize via a slight variant to that method:

```
FERehideSymbols[syms__] :=
  With[{stuff =
     Map[
       Function[Null, {Context@#, SymbolName@Unevaluated@#}, 
        HoldAllComplete],
       HoldComplete[syms]
       ] // Apply[List]
    },
   KeyValueMap[
     FrontEndExecute@
       FrontEnd`UpdateKernelSymbolContexts[
        #,
        $ContextPath,
        {{#, {}, #2, {}, {}}}
        ] &,
     GroupBy[stuff, First -> Last]
     ];
   ];
FERehideSymbols~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
```

---

### Examples:

#### Declare hidden

[image: hidden]

#### Unhide

[image: unhide]

#### Rehide

[image: rehide]

---

### Warning:

All symbol coloring is inherently a little bit fragile (unless you initially hid your symbols with `` Internal`SymbolList[False] ``). Consider the case of:

```
FESetSymbolColoring[Global`a, "Defined"]
Global`a // Clear
```

Nothing seems to have happened, but that's just because `Clear` sticks `` Global`a `` onto the fourth list in the `SymbolList` and `` FrontEnd`Private`GetUpdatedSymbolContexts `` picks this up and removes the coloring.

So you need to set the coloring *after* all definitions, etc. are locked in.

---

### Update:

QuantumDot asked about the second and fourth arguments of that last list. I'll get into a fuller description, but here's some evocative code to guide the discussion:

```
With[{
  a = Unique[a],
  b = Unique[b],
  c = Unique[c],
  e = Unique[PacletManager`testSymbol
     (*Chosen because on $ContextPath and not System` or Global`*)
   \
 ]
  },
 a = 1;
 a // Clear;
 b = 1;
 c = 1;
 c // Remove;
 e = 1;
 Last@Internal`SymbolList[]
 ]

{{"Global`", {}, {"c$2909"}, {"b$2908"}, {"a$2907"}}, \
{"PacletManager`", {"testSymbol"}, {}, {"testSymbol$2910"}, {}}, \
{"System`", {}, {}, {}, {"ToExpression"}}}
```

Note that the cleared symbol is passed to the 4th list, the symbol given a value is passed to the 3rd, the removed symbol is passed to the 2nd, and the non-Global symbol given no value (but introduced via Shift-Enter) is passed to the first.

Now here's the code I've been using to play with symbol coloring:

```
feSomethingWithSymbols[
   {syms__},
   cont : _String | Automatic : Automatic,
   contPath : {__String} | Automatic : Automatic,
   which : 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | {(1 | 2 | 3 | 4) ..},
   echo : True | False : True
   ] :=
  With[{stuff =
     Map[
       Function[Null,
        If[StringQ@Unevaluated[#],
         Replace[StringSplit[#, "`", 2], {
           {c_, s_} :>
            {c <> "`", s},
           {s_} :>
            {$Context, s}
           }],
         {Context@#, SymbolName@Unevaluated@#}
         ],
        HoldAllComplete
        ],
       HoldComplete[syms]
       ] // Apply[List]
    },
   FrontEndExecute@
    FrontEnd`UpdateKernelSymbolContexts[
     Replace[cont, Automatic :> $Context],
     Replace[contPath, Automatic :> $ContextPath],
     If[echo, Echo, Identity]@KeyValueMap[
       With[{symlist = #2},
         Prepend[Replace[cont, Automatic :> #]]@
          Fold[
           ReplacePart[#, #2 -> symlist] &,
           ConstantArray[{}, 4],
           Flatten@{which}
           ]
         ] &,
       GroupBy[stuff, First -> Last]
       ]
     ]
   ];
feSomethingWithSymbols~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
```

Basically it's an easily customizable call to `UpdateKernelSymbolContexts`.

And we'll add a convenient `stateQ` function to specify whether a symbol is blue, red, or black:

```
stateQ[sym_] :=
  With[{s = Mean /@ Transpose@Flatten[ImageData@#, 1]},
     Which[
      Last@s > .9,
      "Undefined",
      First@s > .9,
      "Shadowed",
      True,
      "Defined"
      ]
     ] &@Rasterize[Cell[BoxData@ToString@Unevaluated@sym, "Input"], 
    "Image"];
stateQ~SetAttributes~HoldAllComplete;
```

And here's a convenient testing function (which will show some interesting stuff):

```
testSyms[{syms__}, pre_: Null, testList_] :=
  (
   Quiet[Remove[syms]];
   pre;
   feSomethingWithSymbols[{syms}, testList];
   stateQ[syms]
   );
testSyms~SetAttributes~HoldFirst
```

#### {1} -- Used by: defining symbols without values

```
testList = {1};
"test1" -> testSyms[{test1}, testList]
"test1" -> stateQ[test1] 
(*This differest from testSyms as the FE has time to recolor before \
this is evaluated*) 
"test2" -> testSyms[{test2}, test2 = 1;, testList]
"test2" -> stateQ[test2]
"Print" -> testSyms[{Print}, testList]
"Print" -> stateQ["Print"]
"Global`ToExpression" ->
 testSyms[{"Global`ToExpression"}, testList]
"System`ToExpression" ->
 stateQ[ToExpression]

"test1" -> "Defined"

"test1" -> "Undefined"

"test2" -> "Defined"

"test2" -> "Undefined"

"Print" -> "Defined"

"Print" -> "Defined"

"Global`ToExpression" -> "Undefined"

"System`ToExpression" -> "Shadowed"
```

We can see that *almost* nothing happened. All that really happened was that `` "System`ToExpression" `` noted a symbol conflict.

One other interesting thing to note is that when symbols are passed into the evaluator they clearly get marked as defined, even if they have no values to them.

#### {2} -- Used by: Remove

These are symbols that are noted as unknown by the front-end no matter what they are:

```
testList = {2};
"test1" -> testSyms[{test1}, testList]
"test1" -> stateQ[test1] 
(*This differest from testSyms as the FE has time to recolor before \
this is evaluated*) 
"test2" -> testSyms[{test2}, test2 = 1;, testList]
"test2" -> stateQ[test2]
"Print" -> testSyms[{Print}, testList]
"Print" -> stateQ["Print"]
"Global`ToExpression" ->
 testSyms[{"Global`ToExpression"}, testList]
"System`ToExpression" ->
 stateQ[ToExpression]

"test1" -> "Defined"

"test1" -> "Undefined"

"test2" -> "Defined"

"test2" -> "Undefined"

"Print" -> "Undefined"

"Print" -> "Undefined"

"Global`ToExpression" -> "Undefined"

"System`ToExpression" -> "Defined"
```

#### {3} -- Used by: Giving values

These are noted as defined, no matter what they are:

```
testList = {3};
"test1" -> testSyms[{test1}, testList]
"test1" -> stateQ[test1] 
(*This differest from testSyms as the FE has time to recolor before \
this is evaluated*) 
"test2" -> testSyms[{test2}, test2 = 1;, testList]
"test2" -> stateQ[test2]
"Print" -> testSyms[{Print}, testList]
"Print" -> stateQ["Print"]
"Global`ToExpression" ->
 testSyms[{"Global`ToExpression"}, testList]
"System`ToExpression" ->
 stateQ[ToExpression]

"test1" -> "Defined"

"test1" -> "Defined"

"test2" -> "Defined"

"test2" -> "Defined"

"Print" -> "Defined"

"Print" -> "Defined"

"Global`ToExpression" -> "Defined"

"System`ToExpression" -> "Shadowed"
```

#### {4} -- Used by: Clear

This seems to check whether the symbol in the `` "Global`" `` context and if it is, marks it as unknown.

```
testList = {4};
"test1" -> testSyms[{test1}, testList]
"test1" -> stateQ[test1] 
(*This differest from testSyms as the FE has time to recolor before \
this is evaluated*) 
"test2" -> testSyms[{test2}, test2 = 1;, testList]
Options[test2] = {"a" -> "b"};
feSomethingWithSymbols[{test2}, {4}];
"test2" -> stateQ[test2]
"Print" -> testSyms[{Print}, testList]
"Print" -> stateQ["Print"]
"Global`ToExpression" ->
 testSyms[{"Global`ToExpression"}, testList]
"System`ToExpression" ->
 stateQ[ToExpression]

"test1" -> "Defined"

"test1" -> "Undefined"

"test2" -> "Defined"

"test2" -> "Undefined"

"Print" -> "Defined"

"Print" -> "Defined"

"Global`ToExpression" -> "Undefined"

"System`ToExpression" -> "Shadowed"
```

Comment: Do you know how to make the symbol appear black, but not appear in the autocompletion list?  That would be very nice.

Comment: @QuantumDot don't know if that's possible via the FrontEnd directly but it *is* however [settable at the system level](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151967/38205) and maybe soon at the paclet level, if Itai Seggev's "[forward] ... to the relevant developer" bears fruit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info!

Comment: @QuantumDot I'll do a bit more digging before throwing up my hands in defeat, but if you look at ``Names["FrontEnd*`*Symbol*"]`` there really isn't much left to cover.

Comment: Its kind of entertaining to play around with this... have you found out what happens if you put the list of symbols in the second or fourth positions of the last argument of ``FrontEnd`UpdateKernelSymbolContexts``?

Comment: @QuantumDot I have some ideas. I'll put up an update.

Comment: @QuantumDot took a while to figure it out, but I think I now know what everything is for.

Comment: Very neat!  Thanks a bunch for your efforts!

Comment: Interestingly, it doesn't seem to work completely right if called from an `.m` file inside a package, to hide certain symbols.  Have you noticed this?

Comment: @QuantumDot It depends what you want to do. I actually *do* use it that way. But I have found it to be fragile, yes.

Comment: So I want to hide all the symbols in a particular context, say ``"`MyPackage`Internal`*"``.  I try to call your `FERehideSymbols[...]` with all the full names of the symbols I want to hide, but it fails to actually hide them in the front end (unless run directly from a notebook window).  I also tried to put ``Internal`SymbolList[False]`` right before ``Begin["`Private`"]`` and ``Internal`SymbolList[True]`` after `End[]` in hopes of making all the ``MyPackage`Private`` symbols blue.  But that doesn't work.  Instead, it made (an apparently random subset) of the main ``MyPackage` `` symbols blue!

Comment: @QuantumDot the ``Internal`SymbolList`` trick only works before a thing is introduced (it just disables all coloring). If you didn't do it from a fresh kernel it won't work. On the other hand `FERehideSymbols` should be working, but as it's written there, it works just on symbols, not on strings. Try ``feSomethingWithSymbols[Names["MyPackage`*"],{2}]``. I made sure to support strings there. I use a variant of `FERehideSymbols` in my own packages and it seems to work just fine there.

Comment: @QuantumDot look at the end of this .wl file https://github.com/b3m2a1/mathematica-BTools/blob/master/BTools.wl for what I do (it's auto-configured, so forgive any funky formatting).