# Is it possible to set autocompletion, when the variable name starts with $, ignore it?

Tags: front-end, autocomplete

I need to use variables like \$ + capital letters(\$A,\$B,...) frequently in a project, the default autocomplete always pops up automatically, in most cases, it's a distraction. Can we set Mathematica to ignore the first $ symbol when autocomplete?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest option would of course be to simply change the variable names to start e.g. with `§` or any other letter-like character that's easily accessible on your keyboard.

Another option is to remove all symbols, at least as far as the front-end is concerned (see also [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146279/36508)):

```
FrontEndExecute@
 FrontEnd`UpdateKernelSymbolContexts[
  "System`", $ContextPath, {{"System`", {}, 
    Names["System`$*"], {}, {}}}]
```

[image]

This has the side-effect of causing all `$*` symbols to be colored blue, because the front-end thinks they don't exist. The only way I found to work around this is to use the (rather heavy-handed) mechanism described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151967/36508): You can add all unwanted symbols to your `FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Components", "AutoCompletionData", "Main", "obsoleteFunctions.m"}` file.